# Maximum Capacity with minimum length routing

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph, routes

In virtual circuit packet switching we first establish a dedicated path between the source and destination in the network. Preferably the path length should be small. Again the capacity of the minimum link along the shortest would impose a restriction on the information flow.

So it is preferable to design a cost function i.e., a weighted combination of path length and the minimum link capacity. Since we want to reduce the path length l and want to increase the minimum link capacity c<sub>min</sub> our cost function can be either to maximize **( w<sub>1</sub>* f(c<sub>min</sub>) - w<sub>2</sub>*g(l ))** where w<sub>1</sub> and w<sub>2</sub> are weights and f and g are either linear or nonlinear functions.

What could be an efficient algorithm for this problem in an arbitrary network??

I have been stuck with this problem over a week and couldn't make any progress so far, i searched different ways to solve this problem and thought over it alot like formulating it as widest path problem. But widest problem considers only capacity of the links, but how to include length factor in the problem.? Or there is other way to approach the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't Dijkstra's algorithm work? While checking for tentative distances, calculate the above function up to the candidate node and update.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal thinking to try this, but here how cmin will be maintained for particular route.

Comment: Yes, as @mcdowella pointed out, it will need modification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Dijkstra works completely unmodified, because the best answer as seen by an intermediate node does not necessarily form part of the best overall answer: if all links immediately connected to the destination node have very small capacity, then routes which do well earlier by providing large capacity are probably pointless.

You *can* use Dijkstra to find the shortest route of capacity at least X, by first of all deleting all links of capacity less than X. If there are very few different link capacities, you could compute the lengths of the shortest route for all possible X. Even if there are many different capacities, you can use binary chop to find the route with largest capacity.

To modify Dijkstra thoroughly, I think you would end up holding, at each node, for all possible capacities Xi, the length of the shortest route to that node using capacity at least Xi for every link.